# Variables and Project Database in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Currently I have views in my database that references views of another database of another SQL Instance. Of course the SQL instance is different for each environnement (Dev, Test, Prod).
We are trying to use Database project in Visual Studio : we used "SQLCMD Variables" for the connection strings of others databases but now, when we do a comparison of schema it detects all views where we used Variable as changed (it does'nt replace the variable per its default value).

Is it possible to avoid this problem ? We can modifies our views but we prefer not have to transform them in stored procedure.

Comment: Does the database you compare to have exactly the same connection string as the default on your variable!

Comment: I'd look at Publish Profiles and set the variables for Dev, Test, and Prod to the appropriate Server/DB names. They should then update the variables when you try to publish using each profile.

Comment: When I publish it's ok, it's when I use schema compare than the problem occurs.